# Pygame - How to implement blocks that can collide with each other?

Tags: python, pygame

These are randomly placed bricks which move along the x-axis, to the left and right from wall to wall. I'd like to have all bricks collide with themselves, for example if one of them hit another brick, the `speed` must be `-speed`.

```
brick = []
for in range(50):
    block = Brick()
    brick.append(block)
```

My code is below:

```
if block.rect.colliderect(block.rect.colliderect):
    block.speed *= -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to add another, nested loop to use the `colliderect` of each block with all other blocks. You also need to check if the two block instances are not the same object `block is not other_block`.

```
for block in brick:
    for other_block in brick:
        if block is not other_block and block.rect.colliderect(other_block.rect):
            block.speed *= -1
```

You could also use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead of the two loops.